# Essentially commuting diagram

Tags: category-theory

Given a diagram in a category $\mathcal{C}$, we all know what it means for the diagram to commute.

One level up, given some diagram of categories $\mathcal{C}_i$ and functors $f_i$,  what does it mean to say that the diagram "essentially commutes". I guess it means that for any two paths of functors $f_i$, their compositions are naturally isomorphic.

Comment: Essentially yes, but the isomorphisms are part of the data of the diagram and will typically be required to satisfy some coherence conditions.

Comment: So in general "essentially commutes" does not have a precise meaning and should be specified precisely in each context?